# Missing data in predictors, covariates and outcomes: can i impute them all together?

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I have a dataset of ~5,000 participants. I have missing data in my predictor variables, my covariates and my outcome measures.  All of the measures are highly correlated.

Should I...

(a) impute them all in the same imputation model

(b) impute them in separate models

(c) only use participants with full outcome measures and impute the other variables together

Or a better (d) option?!

Many thanks

Comment: Imputation can lead to bias, especially if missing data forms a large chunk of data. Avoid if possible.

Comment: @ArunJose multiple imputation is pretty much the standard when it comes to dealing with missing data. Could you elaborate on your statement.

Comment: @Maarten - When one imputes data, you effectively are not creating new information but are reinforcing information already available in your existing sample. A general rule that I follow is to try all possible "other" approaches to find missing information before you resort to imputation. One way to assess this is to model data with complete cases only and contrast it to the model you achieve post imputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your assumptions in your imputation model are exactly met (usually a MAR or some well-specified modification of it), then you can do multiple imputation for everything together. However, people are often a bit cautious about doing that. For example, you could imagine that when you apply a drug to patients then predictors and outcomes might be correlated differently than in people that receive a placebo. So, one common strategy is to impute separately within the groups you wish to compare in the end - assuming that each group is large enough to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If the level of missingness is low and a MAR or MCAR mechanism can be assumed, then you can use multiple imputation to impute for all variables including the response variable. No need for separate models

Comment: Missingness for the outcome variables is low (~5%), however missingness for some of the covariates and a few of the predictor variables is high ~45%.  They are definitely not MCAR, but I think that the missingness could be accounted for by the covariates making it MAR.

Comment: You may want to take care imputing a variable with up to 45% missing data. I'm not sure if there are studies that determine a cutoff for when not to impute data but I tend to draw a line (without any formal reason) at 10% if my study is meant solely for inference.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll have think about that.  I've read a few things which talk about multiple imputation as being used on up to ~50% missing data and i'll be comparing it to a complete-case analysis but I'll will think about reducing this figure further.  Aside from this matter, does it make sense to impute all of the data together?  Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to. I read so in a book, missing data analysis, by Cenders

Comment: This might help: https://ideas.repec.org/p/boc/usug11/23.html

Comment: Whether it's 1%, 10% or 50%, in theory if your assumptions are severely violated things can go wrong as badly as possible irrespective of that number. In practice, it is of course the case that more missing data are worse. But what do you do? Not impute = not analyze the data? Complete case analysis is certainly the most stupid thing one could do instead, because it makes even stronger assumptions than any reasonable imputation method.